# -400px on Smooth Scroll

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, smooth-scrolling

I've got some jQuery that adds smooth scroll to my site. On mobile, the fixed header is around 400px in height so scrolls over about 400px of content which includes the title etc. Is there a way to make sure that on mobile the fixed header doesn't scroll over that 400px of content. Here's my jQuery but doesn't seem to be working:

```
//SMOOTH SCROLL
jQuery(function ($) {
// Add smooth scrolling to all links
$("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
        
        // Prevent default anchor click behavior
        event.preventDefault();

        // Store hash
        var hash = this.hash;

        // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
        // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 400
        }, 2000, function(){
   
            // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
            window.location.hash = hash;
        });
    } // End if
});
});
```

Thanks,
Meg

Comment: How are you creating your "fixed header"?  Only the non-header parts should scroll?  Do you have a non-header "filler" at the top, behind the fixed header?  Sounds like a header overlay rather than "fixed".

Comment: Also note that `$('html, body')` will run twice, which may not be a problem here, but has been on other SO questions (that used the complete callback).

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code that I got from another stackoverflow post sometime ago

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
    var offset = -400; // <-- change the value here to fit header 
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top + offset
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

And HTML

```
<a href="#demo">demo</a>

<div id="contact"></div>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I got this code from stackoverflow ages ago so I don't know the link to the answer. I also don't know the exact question where this code is from so I am not sure if it is a duplicate.